# Will React Native optimise images for Android bundle?

Tags: react-native

I'm coming from native Android background and there are a `drawable-**dpi` folders which in final aab bundle will produce lower download size fitting the device properties.

In React Native, what I found, is approach to have `img.png`, `img@2x.png`, `img@3x.png` called by `require("img.png")`.

Will this after generating the aab bundle have same output, or will it increase the final app size?

Comment: Despite Android, React Native doesn't provide compile-time-level images optimization. If you're using embedded local images, compress down to optimal resolution and convert to format like WebP

Comment: ah that misfortune ... "compress down to optimal resolution" do you have any tips&trick how you determine the optimal resolution?

Comment: Webp image files have smaller resolutions and preserve quality. Personally, I don't recommend embedding more images in the app except for things like logo or splash screen.

Other image resource. should be hosted on server and fetch them on demand